# How to reorder ngFor items in component? Angular 2+

Tags: angular, sorting

I am fairly new to Angular so this might be a simple fix.

Currently I have 3 different cards being called with an API. I then use *ngFor to loop over these items and create a card for each one as seen below:

```
<div *ngFor="let exploreCard of exploreCards" class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card three-col">
                        <img class="card-img-top" [src]="exploreCard.ImageUrl" alt="Card image cap" />
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{exploreCard.Title}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{exploreCard.Description}}</p>
                            <p>{{exploreCard.Sequence}}</p>
                        </div>
                   </div>
 </div>
```

You will see that I have a sequence number that is printed out. Now currently my json is sitting so that when the API retrieves it, it is returned in the order `3 , 2 , 1`.

I would like to return it in the order `1 , 2 , 3`. However I know I could use a pipe but I need it to run as quick as possible. I also do not want to just reverse the order of the returned items because that is not sustainable for future additions.

This is the code in my component that runs on initialization:

```
this.exploreService.getExploreCards()
            .subscribe(z => {
                this.exploreCards = z;
                if (this.exploreCards != null && this.exploreCards.length > 0) {
                    this.showLoader = false;
                }
            })
```

and `exploreCards` looks like this:

```
private exploreCards: ExploreCard[];
```

Does anyone know how to achieve correct ordering through logic in the component?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is my `getExploreCards()` method:

```
public getExploreCards(): BehaviorSubject<ExploreCard[]> {
        if (this.exploreCards === null) {
            this.exploreCards = new BehaviorSubject<ExploreCard[]>(null);
            this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}api/Explore/GetExploreCards`).pipe( 
                retry(3) 
            )
                .subscribe((x: ExploreCard[]) => this.exploreCards.next(x));

        }
        return this.exploreCards;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the cards when you retrieve them from service:

```
this.exploreService.getExploreCards()
            .subscribe(z => {
                if(z != null) {
                    this.exploreCards = z.sort((a,b) => a.Sequence - b.Sequence);
                }
            })
```

Or when the cards should be always sorted, then i would put the sorting inside the service.

Or you can write sort pipe ;)

You can also use some utility function instead of native javascript, eg. from lodash to sort by property:

```
_.sortBy(cards, card => card.Sequence );
```

btw. you should not set `this.showLoader = false;` in subscribe, but rather in `finally` operator, so that your loader is no longer visible when your service call fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, check my edit, how do I apply your answer?

Comment: just use `map` in your `pipe()` to remap from unsorted to sorted array, or you can still do it in component, depends on whether the cards should be always sorted or not

Comment: Could you provide an example by chance? Sorry I am really new.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in the component, but in the `getExploreCards()` method:

```
getExploreCards(): Observable<ExploreCard[]> {
  this.http.get('link/to/cards').pipe(
    tap((cards) => cards.sort((a, b) => a.Sequence - b.Sequence))
  )
}
```

Also, think about using the `async` pipe, this will remove the necessity of having to unsubscribe in your components. Otherwise you will have hanging subscriptions, and with it, a memory leak. For example this would be your html then:

```
<div *ngIf="!(exploreCards$ | async)" class="loader"></div>

<div *ngFor="let exploreCard of exploreCards$ | async" class="col-sm">
 <!-- the rest -->
</div>
```

and your ts would be this:

```
readonly exploreCards$: Observable<ExploreCard[]> = this.exploreService.getExploreCards();
```

But that's all up to you :)

-- edit --

To update your method and have a bit easier logic, can use the `shareReplay()` operator from rxjs:

```
private exploreCards = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}api/Explore/GetExploreCards`).pipe( 
  retry(3),
  tap((cards) => cards.sort((a, b) => a.Sequence - b.Sequence)),
  shareReplay() 
)

public getExploreCards(): Observable<ExploreCard[]> {
  return this.exploreCards;
}
```

If you insist on using a `BehaviourSubject` you can use this:

```
public getExploreCards(): BehaviorSubject<ExploreCard[]> {
  if (this.exploreCards === null) {
    this.exploreCards = new BehaviorSubject<ExploreCard[]>(null);
    this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}api/Explore/GetExploreCards`).pipe( 
      retry(3),
      tap((cards) => cards.sort((a, b) => a.Sequence - b.Sequence)) 
    ).subscribe((x: ExploreCard[]) => this.exploreCards.next(x));
  }

  return this.exploreCards;
}
```

Be aware though, that this is very much 'anti-pattern', and leaves room open for hanging subscriptions. Just because your team uses this, doesn't mean it's the right way ;) just my 2c.

Comment: Hi @PierreDuc thanks for the answer, it helps put a lot into perspective. How do I apply this to what I have currently got in my code? I have placed the method in the edit section :)

Comment: @PierreDuc, NOT use tap, you must use map (map change the response, tap not change the response -tap it's use mainly to log a value or to store in a "cache variable"-

Comment: @Eliseo [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) changes the array in place (as well returning the array), so `tap` or `map` can both be used here :)

Comment: @DanielBailey I've updated my answer. Bit untested code, but it should work :) basically the shareReplay operator makes it into a `BehaviourSubject`. So even though the http.get has completed, any new subscription will receive the same array.

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks! I will give it a go when I get the chance.

Comment: @PierreDuc Your solution was still using an Observable, so unfortunately `sort` does not work with `BehaviorSubject`. My project needs to be uniform throughout and we have been using `BehaviorSubject`. In the meantime I used this: ` <div *ngFor="let exploreCard of exploreCards?.reverse()" class="col-sm">`. It will just have to work as a temporary solution. Thanks for the answer though, really appreciate it.

Comment: @DanielBailey I've updated my answer in combination with your precious `BehaviourSubject` ;)

Comment: Thanks! @PierreDuc I have found a solution to my problem without having to dabble in the errors that may possibly come up when using `BehaviourSubject`. In the controller for getting my `exploreCards` I used C# in the following way to order by the Sequence number :`var orderBySequence = from e in exploreCards
                                        orderby e.Sequence
                                        select e;
                    return Ok(orderBySequence);`. Thanks for the input though!